# Implementing Android Action Bar

Tags: android, layout

I am working on creating an Action Bar like the one from the new Android UI Patterns and I am running into a bit of trouble.  I have a `ViewSwitcher` with two layouts in it.  When the user taps the search button I animate between the two layouts.  The problem is that the layouts are different sizes and I can't figure out how to make them take up the same amount of space.  Here's what I mean.  p.s. forgive the bad art, they are just place holders ;)

The red box is right up against the `ViewSwitcher` and there is a gap between that and the action bar for this layout:

[image: Gap]

but not this one:

[image: No Gap]

What I want is to tell the layouts in the `ViewSwitcher` to be the same size.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting android:minHeight on the smaller one to be whatever the height of the larger one is. Or maybe setting it on the ViewSwitcher itself.

---

Idea:

The `ViewSwitcher` only lets you add two `View`s and in your case they are two `ViewGroup`s. You can call `View#measure` on each of the views you're adding to the `ViewSwitcher`. It looks like you should use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for each parameter to `measure`. Then you can call `View.getMeasuredHeight` on each view. What ever is the larger set the smaller view using `View#setMinHeight`.

Comment: The problem that I am having is that I don't know how big the bigger one is.  It depends on the size of the `EditText`.  I've seen three different sizes on three different phones. :(

Comment: I'll try your new suggestion, it's a bit more code heavy though.  I was hoping to keep it in the xml.

Comment: can you just use android:measureAllChildren="false" on the viewSwitcher? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466537/how-to-get-viewswitcher-to-wrap-only-the-currently-displayed-view-height