# How to get ViewSwitcher to wrap only the currently displayed view height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I'm using a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) that lets me easily flip back and forth between two different List Headers with Animations built in.

However, the problem is the two views are of greatly varying height and it appears that the ViewSwitcher with `layout_height="wrap_content"`, measures both children and takes the greater of the two heights as its own.  This results in a large amount of unwanted blank space immediately below the smaller view when it is showing.

I understand why this is desired ViewSwitcher behavior, but it is NOT desired My App behavior.

Example:
Say View A is 50dp tall and View B is 100dp tall and both are added as children to the ViewSwitcher.  The ViewSwitcher always is 100dp tall even with View A showing.

**What I want is to be able to switch between A and B and have the ViewSwitcher shrink or grow to fit whichever view is currently displayed.  How can I do this?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Set the `measureAllChildren` attribute on the `ViewSwitcher` to `false`.

```
<ViewSwitcher
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:measureAllChildren="false">
```

For more info see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#setMeasureAllChildren%28boolean%29).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I thought that was set to false by default in framelayout, but I guess ViewSwitcher overrides that.

Comment: Yes, by default is false. However, you can override it with a theme. Apparently Android's default theme did that, so now, by default is really true. :) Probably Google should either change the documentation or the code.

Comment: @balazsbalazs holy moly its 2022 and it's still behaving that way wtf??